# Prove that if subsequences converge to L, then the original sequence converges to L

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing

Here's the question:

We know that all subsequences of an original sequence $(x_n)$ converge to $L$. For example, $(x_{2n})$, $3n$, ... $mn$ for $m \geq 2$ converge to $L$.

How do I prove that $(x_n)$ converges to $L$?

Here's my attempt:

Assume that $(x_n)$ diverges, i.e. $\exists \epsilon > 0$ such that $\forall N \in \mathbb{N}$, $\exists n \geq N$ such that $|x_n - L| \geq \epsilon$.

Then (tldr) I show that $mn > n \geq N$ which implies $x_{mn}$ diverges which is a contradiction.

My problem is that $x_n$ might also oscillate, but not diverge, and I'm not sure how to go about showing that - my prof mentioned that it might be difficult to show that it doesn't oscillate (at my skill level).

Is there a better way to go about this problem?

Comment: Isn't the starting sequence a subsequence of $L$?

Comment: @JohnDouma if I understand your comment, we don't know that $(x_n)$ is a subsequence of $L$; we only know that starting from $(x_2n)$. I think it was deliberately written this way otherwise the proof would be pretty trivial

Comment: I meant subsequence of $(x_n)$. $L$ is the limit. Yes, a sequence is a subsequence of itself so if all subsequences converge then so does the sequence. Even if you needed a proper subsequence you would just have to remove $x_1$ from the original sequence and you know that converges so the result trivially follows.

Comment: This is a non-standard definition of subsequence.  If you mean that the subsequence made up of every second term converges, the subsequence made up of every third term converges, and so on, then it is not even true that the original sequence has to be convergent.

Comment: I think that the question has to be clarified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact if there are two convergent subsequences $(x_{n_k}),(x_{n_l})$ whose union is the total sequence and converging to the same limit $L$, then $(x_n)$ converges to $L$.

*Proof*:

Given $\epsilon>0$ there are $n_{k_0},n_{l_0}>0$ such that $|x_{n_k}-L|<\epsilon$ and $|x_{n_l}-L|<\epsilon$ for every $n_k\ge n_{k_0}$ and $n_l\ge n_{l_0}$ respectively.

Then for every $n\ge n_0=\max\{n_{k_0},n_{l_0}\}$ we have that $|x_n-L|<\epsilon$, since either $x_n\in(x_{n_k})$ or $x_n\in(x_{n_l})$. Therefore $x_n$ converges to $L$.$\Box$

Of course, the result is true if you have any finite number of subsequences all converging to the same limit, and whose union is the total sequence. This is often used to prove the convergence and calculate the limit of alternating sequences. For example, to see the sequence of Fibonacci numbers' ratios is convergent one can consider the disjoint subsequences $(x_{2n})$ and $(x_{2n+1})$.